# How to Merge Multiple Notification Android?

Tags: android, notifications

How to manage notification with condition:

1. if get single notification then when clicked to launch  to Intent "**DetailNotificationActivity**"  And ,
2. if get multiple notification , the notification always merged on notification bar then when clicked to launch inten "**HomeAplicationActivity**" ?

this s my code, always not merge notification on notification bar and always launch **DetailNotificationActivity** .

```
int icon = R.drawable.icon_notification_comment;    
notification = new Notification(icon, pengomentar+" mengomentari artikel \""+judul+"\" : "+ isi_komentar, when);
 notificationIntent = new Intent(context, ContentCommentActivity.class);                                
 Bundle b = new Bundle();

 b.putString("judul", judul);
 b.putString("komentar", komentar);
 b.putString("sekilas_isi_detail", sekilas_isi);
 b.putString("date", date);
 b.putString("id_tulisan_detail", id_tulisan);
 b.putString("gambar_tulisan_detail", gambar_tulisan_detail);
 b.putString("status_gambar_detail", status_gambar);
 b.putString("kategori_detail", kategori);
 b.putString("main_kategori_detail", main_kategori);
 b.putString("seo_detail", seo_detail);
 b.putString("Notifikasi", "Y");
 b.putString("username", username);
 b.putString("avatar", avatar);
 b.putString("kordinat_lokasi_detail",kordinat_lokasi);

 notificationIntent.putExtras(b);
 notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
 intent =   PendingIntent.getActivity(context, unique_ids, notificationIntent, 0);
 notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, pengomentar+" mengomentari artikel \""+judul+"\"", isi_komentar, intent);

 notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

 // Play default notification sound
 notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

 //notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "your_sound_file_name.mp3");

 // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
 notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
 notification.number += 1;

 notificationManager.notify(unique_ids, notification);
```

How to make it work?

NB: work in from api 8 above